# RemoteApi calls from servlet not loading in local app engine app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'am trying this example https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi
Everything works fine if I run script as java application, but when I do it as servlet it always loads forever and doesn't throw any errors. Also works fine on localhost. Also I noticed it happens when query is made, when I comment it out (datastore.put), servlet loads instantly.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller;
import com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiOptions;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Gae_java_Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

    RemoteApiOptions options = new RemoteApiOptions()
        .server("java-dot-project.appspot.com", 443)
        .useApplicationDefaultCredential();
    RemoteApiInstaller installer = new RemoteApiInstaller();
    installer.install(options);
    try {
        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        System.out.println("Key of new entity is " +
                datastore.put(new Entity("Hello Remote API!")));
    } finally {
        installer.uninstall();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, needed to use RemoteApiOptions().useServiceAccountCredential("service email", "p12key") instead of useApplicationDefaultCredential()